# Using .PYD file in C#?

Tags: c#, python, pyd

I am developing a program using C#, but I just figured out that what I am going to program is very very difficult in C# yet easy in Python. So what I want to do is make a `.PYD` file and use it in C# program, but I don't know how. I've been searching about it but I couldn't find anything.

So these are my questions: How do I use `.PYD` file in C#? I know that `.PYD` files are similar to `.DLL` files, so are `.PYD` files still usable in computers that have no Python installed?

Comment: Smells like X-Y-Problem. What are you trying to do that is so hard in C# but easy in Python?

Comment: You can try using the IronPython script host.

Comment: have you tried pythonnet? https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

Answer (score 2):

A .pyd file IS a DLL but with function init*() where * is the name of your .pyd file. For example, spam.pyd has a function named `initspam()`. They are not just similar, but ***the same***! They ***are*** usable on PCs without Python.

---

Do not forget: builtins will NOT be available. Search for them in C, add them as an extern in your Cython code and compile!

Comment: Hey, that is for Python 2. Also, you need to go through the python<version>.dll API for this to work, which Pythonnet does. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Use [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet)

### Tutorial

You need a GIL state.

```
using (Py.GIL())
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Inside the GIL block, create a scope.

```
using (Py.GIL())
{
    using (PyScope scope = Py.CreateScope())
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

To execute code:

```
scope.Exec(codeStr);
```

To set a variable:

```
scope.Set(name, value); // 'name' is a string and 'value' is a 'PyObject' object.
```

To convert to `PyObject`:

```
obj.ToPython()
```

Convert to `PyObject` if you need to put your object into Python.

To evaluate<sup>[[0]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/160524/evaluating-arithmetic-expressions)[[1]](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)[[3]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)[[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163224/python-evaluate-math-expression-within-string/56955862#56955862)</sup> an **expression**:

```
scope.Eval(expr)
```

To get a variable<sup>[[5]](https://realpython.com/python-variables)[[6]](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp)</sup> value:

```
scope.Get(variableName)
```

C# code that doesn't have an end semicolon before any comment and is one-line represents an **expression**.

## References

0: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/160524/evaluating-arithmetic-expressions
1: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval
2: [What does Python's eval() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do)  on SO
3: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html
4: [Python - Evaluate math expression within string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163224/python-evaluate-math-expression-within-string/56955862#56955862) on SO
5: https://realpython.com/python-variables
6: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp